# Regex - modifying python list

Tags: python, regex, list, tuples, replace

I have a huge list in python that looks like this:

```
('foo','bar','foo/bar','foo1','bar/1')
```

Each value above demonstrates the character variety that the list contains - aplhanumeric plus slash. I need a way to turn that list into a list of tuples, like this:

```
(('foo','foo'),('bar','bar'),('foo/bar','foo/bar'),('foo1','foo1'),('bar/1','bar/1'))
```

So what better way to do this than Regex search and replace, right? (correct me if I'm wrong).

I am therefore trying to match anything between the quotes except for the commas, because technically, they are also between quotes. I used lookahead and lookbehind to match anything:

```
(?<=')(.*?)(?=')
```

But that only matches the values within the quotes and the commas. What I need is to match the value plus the quotes except the commas, and use a replacing regex to make the list look like the tuple above.

I can't do this by hand because the list is huge.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You say you have a huge `list`, then you show us a `tuple`, then you talk about parsing it with a regex, which implies that it's a `str`. Which is it?

Comment: Ok, let me clear it up. It is what you see. I need to convert the first to the second. It's a `list` of `str` but I need to convert it to a `tuple` of `str`

Comment: Also, it seems like all you're trying to do is: `tuple((element, element) for element in huge_list)`. Or, even more simple: `tuple(zip(huge_list, huge_list))`. Am I missing something?

Comment: And to convert a `list` to a `tuple`, you just call `tuple`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: It definitely isn't a duplicate of that meta question. And it isn't even really an instance of an XY question. The OP didn't ask "How can I fix this regex?", he asked how to his actual problem, then showed what he tried (the regex). Maybe he tried the wrong thing, but that doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you have a huge `list` of strings. You want a `tuple`, where for each element of the `list`, you have the pair `(element, element)`.

That's exactly what `zip` does, except that it returns a `list` of such pairs in 2.x, or an iterator in 3.x. Either way, you can convert that to a `tuple` just by calling `tuple`. So:

```
tuple(zip(huge_list, huge_list))
```

More generally, if you want to transform a sequence element by element, you can use a comprehension or a generator expression. There are no "tuple comprehensions", but just passing a generator expression to the `tuple` function does the same thing. So:

```
tuple((element, element) for element in huge_list)
```

Or, if you wanted a `tuple` of `(s[0], s[1:])` pairs instead of `(s, s)` pairs:

```
tuple((element[0], element[1:]) for element in huge_list)
```

And so on.

Meanwhile, I can't think of any situation where converting an object into its `repr` to run a regex transformation on it and re-parse it would be a good idea in Python. This isn't just a ["Now they have two problems"](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) issue; parsing the resulting string (and, even if you don't care about safety, figuring out how to deal with things where `eval(repr(x)) != x`) is going to be a harder problem than whatever you started with. So, if you ever spot yourself trying to make that work, take a step back.